# how to include jquery library in Xcode project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, objective-c, ios6

I have a UIWebView which loads local .html files from resource bundle.
everything is working fine except that the Javascript code written inside .html file is not working at all. I don't have .js file to show popup view in .html file. instead of it the JS code is written inside .html file.

here are some screen shots of my xcodeproject :-

[image]

[image]

by looking around over google all i could gather was that, since i am not using network connection inside my app at all,(i am loading everything locally ) the src for jQuery Library isn't being downloaded.

so is there something which can replace
following line in .html file

" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">"

Or Am i going with the wrong approach ??

**EDIT**

if this helps :-

i have also tried opening those .html files in safari inside my MAC.. . . JS code didn't work there too.

well . . .

am i trying to accomplish something impossible here ?... :D

Comment: Is there any error messages ?

Comment: @daguru : no not at all... well.. actually as i said the the .html file is loading pretty well in UIWebView. its just the javascript code  of those .html files not running well when i load them in UIWebView.

Comment: Did you try to put the jquery library locally on your computer ?

Comment: @daguru : yes actually.. what i did was, I opened the link ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js in webBrowser and made another .js file with that text which i later included in Xcode project

Comment: Then did you point to that file in your HTML ? changing  `src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js` with the path of your local jquery.min.js e.g: my_local_folder/js/jquery/jquery.min.js

Comment: wow... dude that just worked fine . . well.. i guess i was adding file  by grouping any folder .. something option.. thanks

Comment: I have posted a response so you can make it as Accepted answer :) Thanks

Comment: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs...", in this case, will load "file:///ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs..." which is going to be a "file not found" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download jquery **locally** and point to your local jquery file into `<script>` tag

**e.g :  local jquery path**

```
/my_local_folder/js/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

**Changing**

```
<script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

**Width the local jquery file**

```
<script src="my_local_folder/js/jquery/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/uiwebview/load-jquery-in-uiwebview/:

after setting the delegate of the web view to some object you can modify the

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
```

method body as follows

if loading from CDN you would do something like:

```
NSString *jqueryCDN = @"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js";
NSData *jquery = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:jqueryCDN]];
NSString *jqueryString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:jquery encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jqueryString];
```

but if you save a minimized JQuery file locally within the bundle you can do:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Jquery" ofType:@"js" inDirectory:@""];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString *jsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

Comment: still the same problem. don't you think this is gonna run the script manually. if my approach isn't wrong then, what i want is to include a local library for javascript which can be used by my .html files inside Xcode. right now its been downloaded from some "ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" server i guess.

Comment: and BTW.. i have already gone through that same tutorial..:) didn't solve my problem

Comment: Do not load it from a CDN, embed it in your app as @daguru suggested. Otherwise your app will be unnecessarily slow to launch (which might get you rejected from the app store) and non-functional without an internet connection (which will annoy users).